# Acceleration of centre of mass

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, reference-frames, mass, free-body-diagram

[image]

In the solution to this question, they have first taken the component of downwards-acting gravity(g) along the incline which is the sin component then again they have taken the component of the gsin along the x-axis and y-axis.

Now my question is how are we supposed to take the component of a component and why not just g in the downwards direction used for calculation of centre of mass?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How are we supposed to take the component of a component ?

There is no reason why you cannot do this - it is just a mathematical procedure. In this case it makes sense because the component of the block's weight perpendicular to the slope is balanced by the normal force from the slope, so we are just left with the component $mg \sin \theta$ down the slope.

> why not just g in the downwards direction used for calculation of centre of mass ?

You could use this approach, but then you have to take into account the vertical component of the normal force, which is $mg \cos^2 \theta$. The net vertical force on the block is $mg (1-\cos^2 \theta) = mg \sin^2 \theta$. You get the same end result i.e. an acceleration of $g \sin \theta$ down the slope.

Comment: Thank you very much